# Project file doesn't change in OKD

Tags: yaml, openshift, airflow, config, okd

I need to edit yaml file of project

```
openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups: 1000000000/10000
openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range: 1000000000/10000
```

I want to have this

```
openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups: 1000/10000
openshift.io/sa.scc.uid-range: 1000/10000
```

When I try to save my change openshif output is:

```
Error "Invalid value: "1000/10000": field is immutable, try updating the namespace" for field "metadata.annotations[openshift.io/sa.scc.supplemental-groups]".
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotations and labels aren't editable via project resource. You can use namespace resource instead of it:

```
oc edit namespace <namespace_name>
oc label namespace <namespace_name> "project=dev"
```

or use `kubectl` to apply yaml file.

```
kubectl apply -f <test>.yaml
```